# derivative of a vector function wrt a vector function

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Let $\vec{a}\in R^m$ and $\vec{b}\in R^n$ be two vector functions. Now $\frac{\partial \vec{a}}{\partial \vec{b}}$ is given to us and will be a $m\times n$ matrix.

Here I am assuming that the first row is $\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial b_k}$ where $k=1,\cdots,n$.

Now we want to compute $\frac{\partial \vec{b}}{\partial \vec{a}}$ from the given $m\times n$ matrix. If I take its transpose and then invert each scalar element of the transposed matrix, does the resulting matrix automatically give me my desired $n\times m$ matrix, viz. $\frac{\partial \vec{b}}{\partial \vec{a}}$

Comment: If $m\ge n$ and the given derivative matrix (call it $G$) has full rank (i.e. $\operatorname{rank}(G)=n$) then the desired matrix is given by the Moore-Penrose inverse $G^+$

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to properly invert the matrix. This will require $n=m$ and the matrix to have full rank.

Comment: but the two vectors are not of equal dimension then what should i do?

Comment: @user_1_1_1 In this situation you cannot invert the relation to find $b$ in terms of $a$, so $\partial b / \partial a $ doesn't really make sense.